# Visio button to compare text in excel file; error 438

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to make a visio diagram that you click a button and it searchs and excel file for the "location" once it find the location in the excel file it then copies over a URL and proceeds to open that URL with the default browser. I keep getting runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method. Any ideas?

```
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Mail_Room_Click()


Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
Dim XLWB As Excel.Workbook

Set XLApp = New Excel.Application
Set XLWB = XLApp.Workbook.Open("C:\printers\schprint.xlsx")
Set XLWsht = XLWB.Sheets(1)

Dim URL As String
Dim Location As String
Location = "Mail Room"
URL = ""

For Each i In XLWsht.Range("D2:D11")
If StrComp(i.Cells.Value, Location) = 0 Then
    URL = i.Cells.Offset(7, 0).Value
    Exit For
    End If
    Next i


CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run (URL)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing as 's' in XLApp.WorkbookS.Open("C:\printers\schprint.xlsx")
That should fix the problem.